# Haskell: Euterpea PortMidi warning: get_free_output_buffer() wait timed out after 1000ms

Tags: haskell, euterpea

Hi I tried to play a piano song with Euterpea, but after playing it for a few seconds it just gives me the error msg:

```
PortMidi warning: get_free_output_buffer() wait timed out after 1000ms.
```

repeatedly until I disrupt the program. I'm using Windows and according to the quick tutorial on their website I dont need to install any additional programs to work with the library. This piece of code is enough to get the error message:

```
let caChord = chord [c 3 qn, a 2 qn]
    doubleCa = times 2 caChord
    lowerHand = line [f 2 qn, doubleCa]
in play $ chord [line [times 3 (line [e 5 en, f 5 en]),times 3 (line [d 5 en, f 5 en]),times 3 (line [c 5 en, f 5 en]),times 3 (line [bf 4 en, f 5 en])], times 4 lowerHand]
```

Seemingly, it should be pretty obvious of a problem considering that I haven't found any posts about it but faced this error without much trying around.